# Padding between categories in bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I can't figure out how to make the space between categories smaller.
I used:

```
series:{
            pointPadding: 0,
            pointWidth:30,
            groupPadding: 0     
       }
```

If I increase pointWidth to 30 for example the bars overlap each other instead of taking up the white space between.

This is my chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/domino/QzCSa/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `groupPadding: 2` property from 0 to 2

Play with this property and get the width which you want.

Hope this helps